# Number Theory dealing with modulo

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

[image]

I am having a hard time understanding the last part stating that states "the result follows from comparing coefficients". How can you conclude that the coefficients must be 0 (mod p)?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks for helping me type out all the information. :) I'll spend some time learning how to type that kind of text.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we are subtracting the $2$ polynomials modulo $p$.

$$P_1(x)=x^{p-1}-S_1x^{p-2}+S_3x^{p-3}- \ldots-S_{p-2}x+S_{p-1} = 0 \pmod p$$

Has $p-1$ roots and so does the polyonomial :
$$P_2(x)=x^{p-1}-1 = 0\pmod p$$

Subtracting these both, 
$$P_1(x)-P_2(x)=-S_1x^{p-2}+S_3x^{p-3}- \ldots-S_{p-2}x+S_{p-1}+1 = 0 \pmod p$$

we get a polynomial having $p-1$ roots, but it's a polynomial with degree $p-2$.

This implies that the polynomial is none else than the polynomial $P(x)=0 \pmod p$

Now, since this has become an identity that $$\forall x \in \mathbb R~~ -S_1x^{p-2}+S_3x^{p-3}- \ldots-S_{p-2}x+S_{p-1}+1 = 0 \pmod p$$

This implies that $p \mid S_i ~\forall i \in \{1,2, \ldots , p-2 \}$

Also, $S_{p-1}+1=0 \pmod p$ because $S_{p-1}$ is none else than $(p-1)!$, and by Wilson's Theorem : $$(p-1)!+1 = 0\pmod p$$

Comment: Wait, how does it imply that the polynomial is none else than the polynomial P(x) = 0 (mod p). This was the part where I got stuck for like an hour or more because I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: @Anonymous Because a polynomial of degree $n$ cannot have more than $n$ roots, if it is so, It's the zero polynomial, i.e constant and $=0$.

Comment: Anyways, does this prove wilson's theorem?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, It does, I too noticed that just now.

Answer (score 0):

What it's trying to say is that:
$$(x-1)(x-2)...(x-(p-1))=x^{p-1}-1$$
in $Z_p[X]$ - that's because they have the same roots, their degrees are less than $p$ and have the **same leading coefficient**. Because they are equal as polynomials, their coefficients are also equal and thus you get $S_i \equiv 0$ for $i\le p-1$.

Comment: That doesn't quite work, because two different degree-$n$ polynomials can have $n$ roots in common. We need _additionally_ to observe that the _leading coefficients_ are equal before we can be sure the polynomials are identical.

Comment: (Alternatively, we could use Wilson's theorem to conclude that the two polynomials _also_ agree at $x=0$).

Comment: Oh, yes. I should've mentioned the fact about leading coefficients. Thanks!